# Error restore backup SQLSERVER 2008R2 to SQLSERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, sql-server-2008-r2

When I try to restore a backup from sqlserver 2008 R2 to sqlserver 2008, I have the following error:
[image]

There's a way to make a compatible backup ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't because the structure is incompatible (can't go backwards).

Look at solutions like SSIS transfer between two connected servers, or if the database is small, script out the create db objects + insert data statements and execute on the other.

Or purchase some tool e.g. [from Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) for this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use R2 Futures in data base... You can generate script database (schema and data) in sql server 2008 R2.

Then create a database none any object. And run script for this data base in sql server 2008.

You find how to generate script database with data [Click here](http://csharpdocs.com/sql-server-generate-database-schema-data/)